# php for loop syntax: how to impose multiple conditions

Tags: php, for-loop, syntax

For a daily calendar application, I want to print out the hours of the day from nine in the morning to eight at night.  I am using the following syntax which works up through 12.  However, then I want to restart the numbering on 1 and have it continue to 8.  I know this could be done in a more complicated way with multiple if then expressions and so forth but hoping there is a clean way to do it with one elegant expression.  This is partly because there is a database query in the midst of this that I would like to write out only once.  Here is basic code:

```
PHP
//following works up to 12
for($hourofday = 9; $hourofday <= 12; $hourofday++): 

//I want to do something like following but the following does not work.

//for($hourofday = 9; $hourofday <= 12 || $hourofday >=1 && $hourofday <=8); $hourofday++): 
    $output.= $hourofday.':00';
//This is where dbase is queried for events and there is formatting so it looks like a calendar

endfor
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It starts at 9, therefore it will never be between 1 and 8.

Comment: yes.  Should the first term be a throwaway such as $hourofday=0 and have all the conditions in the second term?

Comment: Why not just start with 1 and continue up through 8?

Comment: I want 9am to 12PM and then 1PM to 8PM so I need to iterate through both intervals sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for($hourofday=9; $hourofday <= 20; $hourofday++)
{
    if($hourofday > 12)
        $output .= $hourofday - 12 . ':00';
    else
        $output .= $hourofday . ':00';
}
```

or the shorter but harder to read way:

```
for($hourofday=9; $hourofday <= 20; $hourofday++)
{
    $output .= ($hourofday - ($hourofday > 12 ? 12 : 0)) .':00 ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better to loop over the hours using a 24-hour model and use the [modulo operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to reduce to the 1-12 range in order to display:

```
for ($hourofday = 9; $hourofday <= 20; $hourofday++): 
    $displayhour = $hourofday % 12 ?: 12;
    echo $displayhour.":00\n";
endfor;
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/1x4scN)**.

Modulo 12 puts the hour in the [0, 11] range, but we want to display `0` as `12` -- that's where the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `?:` comes in.

You can easily extend the logic to print AM/PM by simply checking if `$hourofday` is less than 12 or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($hourofday = 9; ; $hourofday = $hourofday%12 +1):
    //do whatever you want, then the last line:
    if($hourofday === 8) break;
endfor
```

Comment: This would break if they wanted an interval of 12 hours or more.

Answer (score 1):

> I want 9am to 12PM and then 1PM to 8PM

In that case you should start at 9 and end at 20, and take the modulus by 12 when outputting.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
for($hourofday = 9; $hourofday <= 20; $hourofday++):
  $hr = ($hourofday > 12)?$hourofday-12:$hourofday;
  $output.= $hr.':00';
endfor
```